# Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am integration Project 2 with Project 1(maven projects).Project 2 tests are not starting because of
Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed;

Details:

Project 1:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Project 2 dependencies:

```
<properties>
  <spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
</properties>

<dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

After adding my dependencies in project 1 pom.xml

Test Runner:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, initializers = {
        ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class })
```

My Junit Test are not starting at all and below is the error:
Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed;

I cannot change Project 1 dependencies or remove them.I can change the dependencies and the version in project 2.

Googled - some solution say that the spring dependencies are causing issue.But i am not able to fix it

Please help.Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing a multitude of versions of Spring, Spring Boot and what not more. That is trouble waiting to happen. So ofcourse it won't work.

Comment: Project 2 when run independently works as expected.Problem is with the integration.

Comment: The problem isn't the integration the problem are the dependencies, they are a mess, and the mess becomes even bigger if you add project 1 as a dependency. Next to that your test is flawed you either use `@SpringBootTest` or `@ContextConfiguration` not both. At least both aren't helping!.

Comment: How can i fix these dependencies?Do you mean i need to update Spring dependencies in Project 2 which are compatible with the hibernate version in Project 1

Comment: No. Fix the dependency mess. Never mix jars of different versions of a framework. If you want a newer version of hibernate just use it (your project will override those from Project 1).

Answer (score 1):

For starters your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing at least different versions of Spring and Spring Boot. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework as that is trouble waiting to happen.

Remove the `spring-context`, `spring-core` and `spring-web` dependencies, those are part of the starters. Remove the `<version />` tag from the Spring Boot starters (assuming you are using the Spring Boot Starter Parent as the parent, else replace the actual version with `${spring-boot.version}` to use consistent versioning.